# Re-ordering rows wrecks multiple selection uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have enabled allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing and canMoveRowAtIndexPath for my tableview.

In editing mode, I can see the selection boxes on the left of the cells as seen below.
[image]

However, now when I try to re-order the rows, the rows lose the selection box as seen below.
[image]
[image]
Any ideas?

EDIT: I do a tablereload at the end of moveRowAtIndexPath:moveRowAtIndexPath: function and this wrecks things up. If I disable the reload, the problem doesn't exist anymore. How do I preserve selection while reloading a table?

Comment: Are you making sure not to throw out the selection circle UI in your prepare for reuse?

Comment: I don't have any special code for selection circle UI in my cellForRowAtIndexPath function. The selection circles just show up when tableview is in editing mode.

Comment: Are you using autolayout with the cell

Comment: Did you re-check on cellForRowAtIndexPath if you really update all cells (and do not leave something initialized from a previous cell)?

Comment: @k6sandeep Yes, I am using autolayout.

Comment: @Senior Yes, I did check that I update all cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath